# Is it possible automatically decline calls with using objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to develop an application to decline annoying calls automatically.
Is there any library/framework that i can use for this aim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot listen to call enter events, or even do something with the phone app except dial to a number.

Comment: *Except present a dialog asking the user to dial a number if they would like to.

Comment: You right... forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is only possible to know about cellular calls using the CTCallCenter (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604).

It is not possible to interact with the calls. It is expected for your application to yield to the phone app upon incoming calls.

Using "tel:" URIs it is theoretically possible to launch a call but I never really tried it my self.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to block a call from particular number in iOS right now. At least not in a way that would get you AppStore approval.